# Do the Bracers of the Merciful Knight also affect the ability to channel positive energy?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, magic-items, paladin

How I am supposed to combine these two pieces of information?

From the description of the bracers:

> When worn by a paladin, he is considered four levels higher for the purposes of determining the uses per day and healing provided by his lay on hands class feature.

From the Paladin class Feature:

> When a paladin reaches 4th level, she gains the supernatural ability to channel positive energy like a cleric. Using this ability consumes two uses of her lay on hands ability. A paladin uses her level as her effective cleric level when channeling positive energy.

May I deduce that the +4 from the bracers also affects the effective cleric level needed to use Channel Energy?

Answer (score 11):

**Not by RAW, no**

Though the Channel Energy ability consumes uses of Lay on Hands, *it is not Lay on Hands*. As a result, the bracers do not affect Channel Energy directly. *However*, they will still grant additional uses of Lay on Hands, which you're free to spend howsoever you wish (such as, say, by fueling Channel Energy).

Comment: Also, if you **really** prefer it the other way, you can simply houserule it.